# Update entity mixed in

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I have two base classes that I can't modify and that have some API in common.

I would like to extend this API in a new class and be able to use this new class independently of the base class.

Something like (where '...' are code parts that I don't know how to fill):

```
class external_1(object):
    """can't modify this class"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print ". init external 1"
    def set_x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    def get_x(self):
        return self.__x

class external_2(object):
    """can't modify this class"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print ". init external 2"
    def set_x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    def get_x(self):
        return self.__x

class new_class(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
    def update(self, ...):
        self.set_x(5)  # parent class's method

x = external_1()
x.set_x(7)
print x.get_x()  # shows 7

new_x = new_class(...)
new_x.update()  # same call seemless of external_1 or external_2 choice
print new_x.get_x()  # shows 5
print x.get_x()  # should show 5

x = external_2()
x.set_x(7)
print x.get_x()  # shows 7

new_x = new_class(...)
new_x.update()  # same call seemless of external_1 or external_2 choice
print new_x.get_x()  # shows 5
print x.get_x()  # should show 5
```

I have tried mixins but didn't succeed to updating the original object (e.g. x.get_x() would show 7 after the new_x is updated).

UPD. Here's my mixin approach code (won't run as I can't paste here the external classes and mesh initialisation instructions):

```
# these are external, generated by swig from c++
from external_module import UnstructuredMesh, StructuredMesh


class MeshElementMixin(object):
    """
    Common services to be added to mesh elements via python's mixin
    mechanism. A mesh element is a block when dealing with structured grids or
    a mesh in case of unstructured grids.
    """
    def __init__(self, fs_element):
        self.__fs_element = fs_element

    def update(self):
        if not self.HasParameter('reynolds'):
            self.SetParameter('reynolds', 1000.)

    def update_external(self):
        if not self.__fs_element.HasParameter('reynolds'):
            self.__fs_element.SetParameter('reynolds', 1000.)


def mesh_element_factory(fs_element):
    if not isinstance(fs_element, UnstructuredMesh) \
        and not isinstance(fs_element, StructuredMesh):
        raise Exception('unknown mesh type in the mesh element factory')

    def mixin_init(cls):
        """A decorator forcing the mixin class to call all base classes __init__ methods"""
        class_init = getattr(cls, '__init__', None)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """ __init__ function for the mixed class """
            for base in cls.__bases__:
                base.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            if class_init:  class_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # make the local function the class's __init__
        setattr(cls, '__init__', __init__)
        return cls

    @mixin_init
    class MeshElement(fs_element.__class__, MeshElementMixin): pass

    return MeshElement(fs_element)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs_element = UnstructuredMesh(initialized_somehow_externally)
    mesh_element = mesh_element_factory(fs_element)

    mesh_element.update()
    print mesh_element.HasParameter('reynolds')  # ==> True  :)
    print fs_element.HasParameter('reynolds')    # ==> False :(

    mesh_element.update_external()
    print mesh_element.HasParameter('reynolds')  # ==> True
    print fs_element.HasParameter('reynolds')    # ==> True :) but does this mean I have to redefine all base class updaters in MeshElementMixin?
```

Comment: You're going into wild territory here with `__` attributes and uncooperative base classes. If you expect an answer, you should make your example code **VERY** much like the code you really have, or just paste the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around in the "wild territory with __ attributes", I have given a try to the "composite" design pattern and to using **getattr** in order to force the class to search for included's object methods and attributes when those are not available in the "new class". No mixin, no factory. More or less the following:

```
class MeshElement(object):
    def __init__(self, fs_element):
        self.__fs_element = fs_element

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.__fs_element, attr)

    def update(self):
        # MeshElement class does not provide "HasParameter" and 
        # "GetParameter" so the __fs_element will be directly affected
        if not self.HasParameter('reynolds'):
            self.SetParameter('reynolds', 1000.)
```

and

```
fs_element = UnstructuredMesh(initialized_somehow_externally)
mesh_element = MeshElement(fs_element)
mesh_element.update()
print mesh_element.HasParameter('reynolds')  # ==> True  :)
print fs_element.HasParameter('reynolds')    # ==> True  :)
```